# how to import 800 mb sql file in localhost using xampp

Tags: database, import

I have been trying to import my magento website database which size is 800 mb in phpmyadmin xampp and having error

''You probably tried to upload a file that is too large. Please refer to documentation for a workaround for this limit.''

Answer (score 2):

You can import database using command line

```
mysql -u username -p database_name < file.sql
```

or you can try

```
mysql -u username -p password    // (press enter)
use database_name ;             // (press enter)
source sql_file_name.sql ;     // (press enter)
```

[Refer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17666249/how-to-import-an-sql-file-using-the-command-line-in-mysql)

Comment: i tried with above command but i did not get solution

Comment: it's always works. can you tell me what is error

Comment: i wrote above command after pressing enter i did not get anything

Comment: may be database importing start . i am editing answer

Comment: i am getting error mysql is not interal or external command

Comment: r u working on windows ? if it's window you need add mysql in globle environment or you need to run this command in xampp mysql console

Comment: i tried on xampp mysql console its working for me

Comment: If this solution is works for you then you can accept this answer to help others

Comment: i accept this answer. its is working for me

Answer (score 0):

You should try this.

```
mysql -u root -p db_name < d:\pathToSql\file.sql
```

Comment: i tried bro but i did not get solutions

Comment: is there any error message on your terminal ?

Comment: You should cross check your sql file path, db name and phpmyadmin username.

Comment: the system can not find the file specified

Comment: I think then sql file path is the only problem.

Comment: i have the file in c drive

Comment: mysql -u root -p magento2 <"c:\db\db.sql"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52714/discussion-between-er-sarvesh-v-tiwari-and-ramkishan).

Comment: c:\pathToSql\file.sql

Answer (score 0):

open php.ini, and set the **max_input_vars**  to 300000000, then restart apache

and in localhost/phpmyadmin:

1. Select Database you want to Export
2. On Top tab menu click Export
3. Then click go

Answer (score 0):

you can direct import from your terminal using below command,

```
/opt/lampp/bin/mysql -u root -p databasename < /opt/lampp/htdocs/databasepathtill.sql
```

Hope this will help you

Comment: i am using xampp not lamp

Comment: then just check for mysql file path in place of opt lampp